# http://example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Yet it works fine for:

```
http://www.example.com
```

..and this `$.post` method is requesting a resource on the same server..? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could set the CORS header on those resources to allow access from `http://www.example.com:80` and `http://example.com:80`:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com:80 http://www.example.com:80
```

Answer (score 3):

The two names `example.com` and `www.example.com` are *different*, even though they might point to the same web pages.

Comment: Use exactly the same server name in your post method. You may need to redirect one name to the other so that a consistent name appears in the address bar no matter which address people type.

Answer (score 1):

subdomains are not considered the same as it's sibling subdomains, nor it's top domain. it must be that the `www` that is affecting it, where `www` is considered a "subdomain" of `example.com`